# How to draw on any plane with 3dtools

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

Salvation
I am testing the 3Dtools library (https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools).
I find the idea interesting.

It is possible to define a plane either by 3 points, or by a vector and a point, very well. on the other hand I did not find how to choose this plan to draw above.

So I'm looking for an example of use.

Comment: Marmot was super active on [TeX Topanswers](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=716). you should hang out there :)

Comment: Can you show coordinates of three points that you want to draw?

Comment: Any 3 points which form a plane not parallel to the planes of the frame.
and any vector not parallel to one of the axes